# How to install and configure 'cmake' in MSYS2?

Tags: cmake, mingw-w64, msys

How to install and configure 'cmake' in MSYS2?
I have tried installing the following MSYS packages

[image: Pacman packages]

I am getting the following error on running any cmake commands

'''
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:5 (cmake_minimum_required):
Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
CMake.

Update the VERSION argument  value or use a ... suffix to tell
CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.

-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (project):
The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

```
cl
```

is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (project):
The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:
cl
is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
'''
Please help resolve this error.

Answer (score 4):

You can search for packages on https://packages.msys2.org and find [cmake package](https://packages.msys2.org/base/cmake) :

`pacman -S cmake`

Comment: basically works, where in my case attracted authentication problems for some modules, had to switch of authentication transiently in pacman.conf, then it worked.

Answer (score 2):

CMake on Windows tries to use the MSVC compiler by default (`cl`). To make it use GCC, add following flags: `-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++`.